# VBS File - Pass InputBox input to SLinkFile?

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

So, I have no experience in vbs really, the most I know is writing pretty basic strings in access.  So, after spending an hour trying to figure this out, I'm coming here for help.

What I am trying to do is write a .vbs script that prompts the user to enter the IPAddress of the local machine and then amends that to the of the oLink.TargetPath (After the =)

So far all I have is:

```
Dim IP_Address 
Ip_Address = Inputbox("Enter The Machine IP")

Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = "C:\Dropbox\Personal\Latitude e6430 - Work\Desktop\timekeeping.LNK"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
    oLink.TargetPath = "http://w-sch-fooddb:8675/lfserver/timecard?ip_address="
    oLink.Description = "Clock in or out"   
    oLink.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll, 111"
oLink.Save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String concatenation is done via the & operator:

```
>> Ip_Address = "1.2.3.4"
>> TargetPath = "http://w-sch-fooddb:8675/lfserver/timecard?ip_address=" & Ip_Address
>> WScript.Echo TargetPath
>>
http://w-sch-fooddb:8675/lfserver/timecard?ip_address=1.2.3.4
>>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to put it within the quotation marks, not outside of it. You saved my day....